# iPhone no sound on incoming calls in Guided Access

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, guided-access

I've got my 88 year old grandma the latest iPhone SE and Watch SE and set it up in Guided Access for the Phone app (see attached for the icon).

I also have it set up so she only receives the calls in full-screen phone mode, not banners (aka background mode) - see the second attached image (which was taken on my iPhone 12 Pro, so the UI is not 100% the same as iPhone SE).

The problem is that when she receives a call, the call only rings and is visible on the screen for a split second, as the iPhone's screen turns off and the ringing stops, while the Watch keeps ringing. Basically, the phone puts the call into background mode (gray box  on the top of the screen, instead of green).

When I disable Guided Access, it works as it should. Turning off the Watch doesn't have an effect.

**How do I set it up so when she gets a call, it'll always ring throughout the incoming call, while in Guided Access?**

PS :
I set her phone to Guided Access because she really couldn't use it otherwise - she's 88 and never had a smartphone before. Setting it up in Guided Access was a last-ditch effort to salvage the operation (getting my grandma on an iPhone and a Watch for the sake of being able to videocall and automatic emergency calling if she falls again), as despite a month-long of me training her, she still wasn't able to figure out how to do a simple thing like answer a call. It worked.

**EDIT :**
Talking to Apple customer support, I was told this is [expected behavior](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph7fad0d10/ios).
Does anyone know how to achieve my goal any other way? Basically my grandma only needs to have access to initiating and receiving (or just receiving) FaceTime.

Any more access means she’ll mess up the phone

She can’t have access to Home Screen!

*Phone app icon below*

[image: Phone app icon]

*Incoming Calls screenshot below*

[image: Incoming Calls screenshot]

Comment: I’m assuming you’ve tried using both Banner and Full Screen for the Incoming Calls setting and both of them didn’t work?

Comment: @RyDev That's correct, it doesn't work in other locked or unlocked mode. Sorry for the late response.